# ServiceStack Service Calling Async Methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous, servicestack, async-await

I've a ServiceStack service. Now inside a servicestack service methiod I need to call a Method from a component which is async implemented

```
async Task GetDataAsync();
```

As the ServiceStack methods can't be marked **async** I'm wondering how the best way would be to call this method.

```
return GetDataAsync().Result;
```

Would smells from my point of view.

Whats best practice for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mark ServiceStack methods with async but you will need to upgrade to version 4.

Comment: And yes, the version 4, while still Open Source, is commercially available for non-Open Source projects, so it will cost some money, unless of course your project is OS in which case party on :)

Comment: Correct  version 4 supports async directly.   https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes#wiki-server-side-async-support

Comment: Thanks. Didn't see that a v4 was released

Comment: Well, technically I think @mythz still calls it a beta, but it's been commercially available for some time.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a method which isn't marked `async` but needs to call an `async` method then yes you can use the following pattern

```
return GetDataAsync().Result;
```

However this does mean the  method will now block the caller instead of letting the task complete itself when the requested resource is available.  Whether or not this is OK goes to the core of why the methods in your service stack can't be marked as `async`.